# `WWW::Mechanize Won't Fill Form Out

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to fill out a form on a website using [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) but the form is embedded in a script, not the usual `<form>` tag

```
<script>
    component_lang["ib4"] = {};
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="ib4-tpl">
        <form class="component component-form" id="input" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" >
<div class="input-group type-firstlast">
    <div class="input-label">
        <label>Your Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs columns">
        <div class="column-2 column-first"><input type="text" name="first"  placeholder="First Name" value=""></div>
        <div class="column-2"><input type="text" name="last"  placeholder="Last Name" value=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>     </script>
<li id="ib4" class="form page-component-has-overflow"></li>
```

How would I use `WWW::Mechanize` to fill this form out? The `mech-dump` utility did not find any forms on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WWW::Mechanize only works on the HTML, it has no Javascript support. For a Mechanize-like module with Javascript support, you have several options.

- [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) which lets you drive Firefox.
- [WWW::Scripter](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Scripter) with [WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript).
- [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Selenium) to interface to Selenium RC or [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) to interface to Selenium Webdriver.